# vue.js import a component dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, import, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to import a component dynamically, but all my component and vuex variables seem to be undefined.

```
function loadChart(chartName){
    let chart = chartName + '.vue'
    return System.import('@/components/charts/' + chart)
  }

  export default {
    name: "SingleChart",
    data() {
      return {
        chartTitle: this.$store.getters.getSingleChartTitle,
        chartName: this.$store.getters.getSingleChartName
      }
    },
    methods: {},
    computed: {},
    watch: {},
    props: [],
    components: {
        Chart: () => loadChart(this.chartName)
    }
  }
```

I get the error

```
Reason: Error: Cannot find module './undefined.vue'.
```

Comment: Try without using an arrow function for `Chart`.

Comment: @Thoomas Thanks, can you give an example of how that would look?

Comment: Just to be sure that the problem is with `this.chartName`, have you tried to load a module by hardcoding ITS name as a parameter of `loadChart` ?

Comment: Yes, hard coding the module name works fine. I am starting to think that the point in the vue.js life cycle where components property is evaluated, the store is not available. I have also tried passing a prop via the router and that is also not available. There must be a way to do this, I'm sure I am not the first person to need this.

Comment: Maybe it's because arrow function use the  `this` parent context, so `this` is not the Vue instance. See the warning message above this section : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: If if put console.log(this.$store.getters.getSingleChartName) in the loadChart() function, I get undefined in the console. So even if the this context is wrong in the arrow function, the direct call to the store, should still work if the store was available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173042/discussion-between-prestondocks-and-thoomas).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the Vuex state page](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html), you may not have injected the store to use it as you've referenced (this.$store...)

> Vuex provides a mechanism to "inject" the store into all child components from the root component with the store option (enabled by Vue.use(Vuex)):

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    // provide the store using the "store" option.
    // this will inject the store instance to all child components.
    store,
    components: { Counter },
    template: `
      <div class="app">
        <counter></counter>
      </div>
})
```

Comment: @'Miles Grimes' Thanks, but I have already injected the store. I am starting to think that at the point in the vue.js life cycle where the components property is evaluated, the store is not available. so I need an alternative.

Comment: This appears to be relevant, though not using Vuex: https://medium.com/@codetheorist/using-vuejs-computed-properties-for-dynamic-module-imports-2046743afcaf